# If the DB is locked ora-28000, will it impact ongoing executions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

If the DB is locked ora-28000, will it impact ongoing executions

Please find the below scenario

- A user has logged in and executing a SQL/PLSQL
- B user has entered incorrect password, due to which DB user is locked

Will the existing executing queries continue to run until the user logs off

Comment: AFAIK If the session is active then the queries should continue to run on the Session for User A.

Answer (score 0):

- User A (Rahul) established connection and is allowed to work
- User B (Littlefoot) tried to connect to the same database schema and provided wrong password too many times which caused the account to be locked
- that affects **future connections**; the ones that were previously established work normally until their session is over, which means that

  - if user A (Rahul) disconnects and tries to connect again, although providing correct password, won't be able to connect because account is locked and DBA should unlock it